Some files are missing in Laravel 11
I recently installed Laravel 11, but I’m encountering some issues. I noticed that some files such as Kernel.php, Middleware.php, and api.php are missing. Thinking there was a problem with my initial installation, I reinstalled Laravel 11, but the same files are still missing. Can anyone help me understand what might be going wrong?
I previously worked with Laravel 10 and recently upgraded to Laravel 11. Just installed Laravel 11 twice and encountered the same issue.

You should first review the changelogs for the upgraded version before posting this kind of question here.

You can check this link, this will answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/78612108/21210375

In Laravel 11, the structure has been streamlined, leading to changes in how certain files are handled compared to Laravel 10.
for middleware you can initiate making middleware like it used to using php artisan, and if you want to make the alias of the middleware, you can make it in bootstrap/app.php and make something like this
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->alias([
        'checkrole' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class,
    ]);
})

Regarding api.php, this file is no longer included by default in fresh installations. You can generate it by running: php artisan install:api
here is something to read on
route api laravel 11, 
kernel & middleware

Since Laravel 11, there is no more Http Kernel file in the Http folder, and all necessary configurations have moved to the bootstrap/app.php file.
Here is a Medium article that goes into further detail:
https://rezakhademix.medium.com/laravel-11-no-http-kernel-no-casts-no-console-kernel-721c62adb6ef
It is also mentioned in the middleware section of the Laravel 11 release notes:
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/releases#laravel-11
